# How to preserve the 'this' instance in a callback function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In Angular2 I have a component that uses a service for uploading a file to Amazon S3.

My component (simplified):

```
private _loading = true;

// use service to upload file
this._s3service.uploadFile(fileObject, this.uploadCallback)

// use this function as a callback
uploadCallback(err, data) {
  this._loading = false; // this crashes because of 'this' is referring to service instead of component
}
```

My service (simplified):

```
    private getS3(): any {
       // Get or create AWS instance
       return s3;
    }

    public uploadFile(selectedFile, callback): boolean {
       this.getS3().upload({
            Key: key_name,
            ContentType: file.type,
            Body: file,
            StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
            ACL: 'private'
          }, function(err, data){ // <=== What to do here?!
            callback(err, data)
          });
    }
```

The problem is that when the callback function is fired from the service, `this` is referring to the service and `this._loading` cannot be found.

**Question:** How can I preserve the `this` instance in my callback function, (`this` in the callback must point to `component` and not `service`)

Comment: Possible solution might also be using Instance function https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript#use-instance-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @Gunter is right, I think you want to keep the `this` in the callback you actualy pass to that function :

```
uploadCallback(err, data) {
  this._loading = false; // this is the "this" you want to keep
}
```

then it would be something like this:

```
this._s3service.uploadFile(fileObject, ()=>this._loading = false);
// or 
this._s3service.uploadFile(fileObject, ()=>this.uploadCallback());
// or
this._s3service.uploadFile(fileObject, this.uploadCallback.bind(this));
```

Also note that it might be interesting to use an `Observable` instead of passing a callback :

```
public uploadFile(selectedFile): Observable<any> { // "<any>" because I don't know what is the type of "data"
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
        this.getS3().upload({
            Key: key_name,
            ContentType: file.type,
            Body: file,
            StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
            ACL: 'private'
        }, (err, data)=> {
            if(err)
              observer.error(err);
            else
              observer.next(data);
            observer.complete();
        });
    });
}
```

then:

```
this._s3service.uploadFile(fileObject).subscribe(data=>console.log(data))
```

Comment: You understood my question correct. +1 for suggesting the use of Observables.

Answer (score 11):

Use **arrow functions**

```ts
  }, (err, data) => { // <=== What to do here?!
```

they are for exactly that purpose, for `this` to keep pointing at the class instance where the function is declared.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

If you pass a function reference **`.bind(this)`** might be more convenient, because it doesn't require to list the parameters at all while `=>` would require them twice

```ts
myCallback(err, data){ // <=== What to do here?!
        callback(err, data)
}

public uploadFile(selectedFile, callback): boolean {
   this.getS3().upload({
        Key: key_name,
        ContentType: file.type,
        Body: file,
        StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
        ACL: 'private'
      }, this.myCallback.bind(this));
}
```

The same which arrow functions

```ts
public uploadFile(selectedFile, callback): boolean {
   this.getS3().upload({
        Key: key_name,
        ContentType: file.type,
        Body: file,
        StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
        ACL: 'private'
      }, (err, data) => this.myCallback(err, data));
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, if for some reason you can't or don't want to use arrow functions, you can "bind" the function ( myFunction ( ) { }.bind ( this ) ). That was the pre-ES6 way of going about it.

Comment: I considered adding it, but with the example in the question I don't think it's a good idea. I adapted the example so that it makes more sense.

Comment: I might have not asked clearly enough: The problem is that the callback's 'this' referrers to the service instead of the component. I need the code in the callback to be executed with 'this' pointing at the component (not service). If Im not mistanken your answer shows how to bind 'this' to the service.

Comment: The heading for the first block of code: 'My component (simplified)'.
Im sorry if I was not clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: Again, you can "bind" a function to any "this" you want (it doesn't have to be "this", it can be another component, etc). In that way, "bind" can be more flexible than arrow functions. (Interesting...you can "point" a "bind" anywhere you want, but you can only "point" an "arrow" at one place...secret of all things in there somewhere...)

Comment: Great! This is the definitive solution. Must be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `uploadFile` to return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

and handle the error case from your component as it should be.
Something like

```
    public uploadFile(selectedFile): boolean {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.getS3().upload({
            Key: key_name,
            ContentType: file.type,
            Body: file,
            StorageClass: 'STANDARD',
            ACL: 'private'
         }, function(err, data){ // <=== What to do here?!
            resolve(err, data)
        });
       }
  });
```

And you could from your component do this

```
 this._s3service.uploadFile(fileObject).then((err, data)=> {
   this._loading = false;
 });
```

Comment: why `resolve(err,data)`, why not `resolve(data)` and `reject(err)` ?

Comment: @n00dl3 yes error should be rejected. But in this case, it will depend on the response parameters from the upload function call

Comment: and, what is the problem ??? `(err, data)=>err?reject(err):resolve(data)`

Comment: plus passing `callback` makes no sense in here.

Comment: @n00dl3 yes this should work (if we know that err is falsy for successful uploads)

Comment: @n00dl3 Yes. I forgot to remove that